# beautifulsoup - extracting link, text, and title within child div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The layout is as follows:

```
<div class="App">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">Application Name #1</div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://img_url)">
        </div>
        <a href="http://app_url" class="signed button">install app</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to grab The TITLE, then the APP_URL and ideally, when I print via html, I would like for the TITLE to become a hyper link of the APP_URL.

My code is like this but doesn't yield desire results. I believe I need to add another command within the loop to grab the title. Only problem is, How do I make sure that I grab the TITLE and APP_URL so that they go together? There are at least 15 apps with the class of `<div class="App">`. Of course, I want all 15 results as well.

IMPORTANT: for the href links, I need it from the class called `"signed button"`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(example)
for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'App'}):
    a = div.findAll('a')[1]
    print a.text.strip(), '=>', a.attrs['href']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS selectors:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="App">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">Application Name #1</div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://img_url)">
        </div>
        <a href="http://app_url" class="signed button">install app</a>
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

for div in soup.select('div.App'):
    title = div.select_one('div.title')
    link = div.select_one('a')

    print("Click here: <a href='{}'>{}</a>".format(link["href"], title.text))
```

Which yields

```
Click here: <a href='http://app_url'>Application Name #1</a>
```

Comment: I get this error :    `soup = BeautifulSoup(my_url, 'html5lib')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2.7.egg/bs4/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html5lib. Do you need to install a parser library?` However, when I pip install html5lib, i get this message: `Requirement already satisfied:`

Comment: can we do a private chat?

Comment: okay, I change to what you said, however, it only yield half the results. weird. Oh snap. The website has a tab below that reads "Load More", so it's not picking up everything unless the end user hits "Load More". How can I surpass this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will work?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(example)
for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'App'}):
    a = div.findAll('a')[0]
    print div.findAll('div', {'class': 'title'})[0].text, '=>', a.attrs['href']
```

Comment: it's IMPORTANT for the href links to be from the class called `"signed button"`. - also, The website has a tab below that reads "Load More", so it's not picking up everything unless the end user hits "Load More". How can I surpass this?